# ROS version on RPi 2

Tags: raspberrypi, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I would like to install from http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Debian ROS Indigo Desktop version for a Raspberry Pi 2: is it possible? Because I installed this version but during installation the RPI 2 was on standby and at the end of the process if I type "$ rosversion -d" I get "<unknown>", and I have to re-key "$ source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash".
I have to repeat the installation? Or I can fix that already done? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226312/ros-version-on-rpi-2/) by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

On raspberry pi **2** with raspbian, you should follow the arm installation:

http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM

and you can't have the desktop version, because all package haven't be build for arm processor.
You can check package availability here:

http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_arm.html

---

Originally posted by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) with karma: 357 on 2016-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0